# ClassCastException with H2

Tags: java, jpa, integration-testing, h2

I'm using h2 for testing purposes, but I have problems when casting to a derived class. The case is:

```
    @Entity    
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 64)
    public class A {...}

    @Entity
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 64)
    public class B extends A {...}
```

My dataset looks like:

```
<A attr1=... attr2=... DTYPE="A"/>
<B attr1=... attr2=... DTYPE="B"/>
```

The problem is when I try to do a query in JPA like this one:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE...");
```

and I try to get the value like this:

```
(B) q.getResultList().get(0);
```

I have the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackage.A cannot be cast to mypackage.B
```

In mysql it works fine, but not in H2. 
H2 version: 1.3.171

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end the problem is that the discriminator value doesn't work that well with H2, I expected to have the same behavior that with hibernate and mysql, but that was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `q.getResultList()` returns a list of `A` objects,

`B` extends `A` and therefore, `B` can be cast as `A`. However the reverse is not true. An instance of `A` cannot be cast as `B`.

Comment: The result of the query is always of class B, the problem is that in the database there is no table for B, there is a table for A with a discriminator. So A and B entries are in the same table.

Comment: I think the problem is that H2 doesn't recognize that table A can have entries of type B. Even your explanation is right, my problem is different.